# Julia Parsing a CSV

Tags: parsing, csv, io, julia

Hope the evening is a more than hospitable one and you have traded your emacs terminal for some bonne-vivant Ralph Lauren catalog dinner party type scene. As for me, I'm trying to parse a CSV in Julia and things are deteriorating. Here is my code:

```
f2 = open("/Users/MacBookPro15/testnovo.csv", "r")

skip(f2, 736)

for line in eachline(f2)
    string_split = split(line, ",")
    println(string_split[1])      
end
```

Now if I substitute `string_split[2]` or anything other than `[1]` I get a BoundsError and it's rather frustrating because I need those items. Can anyone tell me how to avoid this?

Comment: Check `length(string_split)` and `for col in string_split println(col) end`. `BoundsError` means that there were no commas on that particular line so there is only 1 element in string_split. As @BenHamner suggests, you have brought a knife to a gunfight and should shop around for a proper CSV parser or at-least a well-debugged regular expression to do this.

Comment: trust me there are commas.

Comment: So debug it. Catch the exception and print the `line` and `string_split` it choked on. Maybe the first or last line is blank. Maybe some Unicode looks like a `,` but isn't. Maybe you found a bug in Julia itself -- there's a few.

Answer (score 7):

Every time I hear "parsing a CSV" I want to duck and cover my ears, before I get flashbacks of a missing quote, or a 32-column line 98% of the way through a 33-column, 10GB csv file.

Fortunately, there are two useful functions that'll prevent you from rolling your own csv parser:

- readcsv in Julia's standard library http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.2/stdlib/base/?highlight=readcsv#Base.readcsv
- readtable in Dataframe.jl http://juliastats.github.io/DataFrames.jl/io.html

Comment: dataframes is out....the file is 8 gigs and it took dataframes 8 hours which ain't gonna work given the fast paced nature of my existence. is there a way to work the readcsv function line by line? Thanks.

Comment: @ChaseCB I'd say check the source for `readcsv` in `base/datafmt.jl` but I did and it's not helpful. It will try to choke the whole file into memory to determine dimensions to allocate storage beforehand. This is no solution for your 8 GB file. You need to stream process with a regular expression. Google "regex csv" for examples.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, it looks like you need the DataStream abstraction, which we stopped including in DataFrames since not enough people worked on it to make it robust. The first 100 lines of https://github.com/JuliaStats/DataFrames.jl/blob/master/prototypes/datastream.jl should provide you with enough information to write your own streaming algorithm for working with CSV's.